# Change Excel date format from YY.MM.DD to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: excel

I'm trying to convert dates from

```
     16.12.07 10:17:51 to 07/12/2016 10:17:51
```

So far I tried using Date, Substitute functions but Excel doesn't recognize this date format. Any suggestions?

Comment: [This](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e) can help you

Comment: Excel doesn't see `.` as a date separator. Do a find and replace on `.` with `/` then set the formatting as date. If that still doesn't work they will be saved as text (you can tell if the date sits to the left of the cell that its text not a date), in which case after find and replace you can use a helper column with `=DATEVALUE(A1)`.

Comment: I tried this as well, doesn't still recognize as a date in Excel

Comment: Rather strangely, you can specify a "." separator in the custom formatting of a cell, so you *could* specify a format "yy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss" and apply it to a cell so that when you subsequently entered a date & time it would convert it to that format. However, blowed if I can kick Excel into applying that format to existing text as standard. It may well be easier to define helper columns, split out the components of the date and time, and then reconstruct a proper DateTime entry from those values with the format you want.

Comment: Thats the bit I was struggling with, preformatting as `yy.mm.dd` works, but to apply that to pre written text was a bit of a mystery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have "16.12.07 10:17:51" in cell A1, in cell B1, use "=left(a1,2)", in cell C1 use "=mid(a1,4,2)", in D1 "=mid(a1,7,2)". Rinse & repeat for the time components.
In cell A2, use "=Date(b1+100,c1,d1) + Time(e1,f1,g1)"
Then format cell A2 to look like you want it to with the custom format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" and it will be as you need it in the most pain-free/full (*) way possible.

(*) - delete as appropriate

Comment: Thanks, its helpful

Comment: Why use helper columns? Just 1 formula `=MID(A1,7,2)&"/"&MID(A1,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(A1,2)&" "&MID(A1,10,2)&MID(A1,12,3)&MID(A1,15,3)`

Answer (score 2):

To convert to a "real" date:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE("20"&A1,".","/")
```

Then format as you want:

dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Notes:

- If some of your dates are prior to 2000, you can incorporate an "if" statement to decide whether to prepend a 20 or 19, depending on the value of the first two digits.
- If your system does not recognize `/` as the date separator, replace that in the `SUBSTITUTE` with the appropriate separator.
- I think most non-US as well as US versions of Excel will interpret the date in a format of `yyyy/mm/dd` as such, but, if yours is non-US, check that possibly ambiguous dates are properly interpreted:  eg 2016/03/02
- If the above doesn't work, it may be that there are `NBSP` characters.  So try this more complex formula:

---

```
=--TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("20"&A1,".","/"),CHAR(160)," "))
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the date, simply use the following:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(cell_location;".";"/")
```

so if we assume a date is in cell A1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";"/")
```

You may need to use commas, but semi colon works for me.

Edit: I see you have tried substitute, however when I reformatted the cells to date, the rest of them auto adjusted when I dragged the cells down. Are you able to simply format the entire column?